# read word doc file stored as blob and convert its content to string

Tags: c#, mysql, interop, blob, console-application

I have a stored word document as BLOB on Mysql and I am trying to read it using c#, get the text inside it. Can someone give me short code on how to do that. so far I have managed to read the bytes from the database using:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "connection string is here";
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select filename, document_content from job_db.person_documents where doc_type = 'application/msword' limit 1;", conn);
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // while there is another record present
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Byte[] bytData = (byte[])reader[1];        
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an office talk article about reading open XML docs from memory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee945362%28v=office.11%29.aspx

To access these methods, you need the Open XML SDK.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.